# Using AssertJ, how do I perform complex assertions on the contents of a list?

Tags: java, assertj

In AssertJ you can do the following to assert the contents of a list:

```
assertThat(list).extracting("name").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Alice", "Bob");
```

I often find myself wanting to do more complex assertions on the elements themselves, e.g., asserting that Alice is a tall brunette and Bob is tiny and bald.
What is the best way to do this using AssertJ?

My own solution is to do:

```
assertThat(list).extracting("name").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Alice", "Bob");
list.stream()
    .filter(person -> "Alice".equals(person.getName()))
    .forEach(alice -> {
        assertThat(alice).extracting("size").isEqualTo("tall")
        assertThat(alice).extracting("hair").isEqualTo("brunette")
    });
list.stream()
    .filter(person -> "Bob".equals(person.getName()))
    .forEach(bob -> {
        assertThat(bob).extracting("size").isEqualTo("tiny")
        assertThat(bob).extracting("hair").isNull()
    });
```

or equivalently (java 7) :

```
assertThat(list).extracting("name").containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Alice", "Bob");
for(Person person : list){
    switch (testCase.getName()){
        case "Alice":
            assertThat(person).extracting("size").isEqualTo("tall")
            assertThat(person).extracting("hair").isEqualTo("brunette")
            break;
        case "Bob":
            assertThat(person).extracting("size").isEqualTo("tiny")
            assertThat(person).extracting("hair").isNull()
            break;
    }
}
```

but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

I like the fact that this solution makes a distinction between the expected elements being in the list and the elements themselves being correct.

Comment: This is a highly simplified example. I encounter the need for this complex assertions mostly when a class contains a collection and I want to do assertions on this inner collection as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For filtering, you can directly use any flavor of [filteredOn](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#filteredOn-java.util.function.Predicate-), then either [allMatch](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-java.lang.String-) or [allSatisfy](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-) (when I say directly I mean no need to stream your collection in order to filter it).

I suggest to explore AssertJ API, you have other assertions like [anySatisfy](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#anySatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-) or using [conditions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html) with method like `are`, `areAtLeast`, ...  the vast majority of the API has javadoc with examples to show how to use it.

Additionally one can have a look at the [examples](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/tree/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples) in the assertj-examples project.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Test
 public void test(){
    assertThat(list).filteredOn(person -> person.getName().equals("Alice")).extracting("size").first().isEqualTo("tall");
    assertThat(list).filteredOn(person -> person.getName().equals("Alice")).extracting("hair").first().isEqualTo("brunette");
    assertThat(list).filteredOn(person -> person.getName().equals("Bob")).extracting("size").first().isEqualTo("tiny");
    assertThat(list).filteredOn(person -> person.getName().equals("Bob")).extracting("hair").first().isNull();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Often I find it's easier to just express the whole expected collection:

```
assertThat(list).containsOnlyElementsOf(Arrays.asList(
    new Person("Alice", "tall", "brunette"),
    new Person("Bob", "tiny", null)
)
```

Comment: This only works if the element assertions are simple. In your answer the `Person`'s `equals` method needs to be implemented correctly and take into account all the values you want, and nothing more. I find this too restrictive. Sometimes I don't care about other fields. E.g., you could add to a person the shoe size, which would be taken into account in the equals method while in the test I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and used the following methods: filteredOn(), first(), returns(), extracting(), asList() and containsExactlyInAnyOrder(). AssertThat is nice because allow you to concatenate all these operations.

```
        assertThat(chatMessageReactionDtos)
            .filteredOn(reaction -> reaction.emojiKey().equals(JOY))
            .first()
            .returns(2, ChatMessageReactionDto::count)
            .returns(true, ChatMessageReactionDto::userSelected)
            .extracting(ChatMessageReactionDto::details)
            .asList()
            .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
                    new ChatMessageReactionDetailDto(
                            reactionJoyUser1.getReactorUser().getId(),
                            reactionJoyUser1.getReaction(),
                            reactionJoyUser1.getUuid().toString(),
                            true
                    ), new ChatMessageReactionDetailDto(
                            reactionJoyUser2.getReactorUser().getId(),
                            reactionJoyUser2.getReaction(),
                            reactionJoyUser2.getUuid().toString(),
                            false
                    )
            );
```